# How can I duplicate two :before in css?

Tags: html, css

I've found this interesting codepen and I'm trying to make 2 storms, one of the left and one on the right. I've tried to duplicate the background id and make it a class but it didn't work. If anyone could help that would be great! 
p.s I'm new into coding.

Thanks

```css
#background {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("https://sharabindu.com/pure_css_rain_with_strom/img/storm-bg.jpg") center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#background:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-animation: flash 5s ease-in infinite;
  animation: flash 5s ease-in infinite;
  z-index: 50;
}

#background:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  content: '';
  -webkit-animation: strome 5s ease-in infinite;
  animation: strome 5s ease-in infinite;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

https://codepen.io/sharabindu/project/editor/ZMKvvb

Comment: There's nothing called *dubligating*!

Comment: @PraveenKumar Inspired by IHOb.

Comment: @ManojKumar Ha ha. Sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to duplicate a :before selector

Still, you need to duplicate something as the storm light and flash are both using `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors

However, no need to duplicate the `#background` element, has both will contain the background image, which will overlap... So, you will never succeed to have the desired rendering.

Instead, try to add 2 new divs inside the background, on which you will apply a new `.storm` class, which will use the `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors for storm and flash

Something a bit like this

**HTML**

```
<div id="background">
  <div class="storm"></div>
  <div class="storm"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#background {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url("https://sharabindu.com/pure_css_rain_with_strom/img/storm-bg.jpg") center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
.storm{position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 50%;}
.storm:nth-of-type(1){left: 0;}
.storm:nth-of-type(2){right: 0;}


.storm:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-animation: flash 5s ease-in infinite;
  animation: flash 5s ease-in infinite;
  z-index: 50;
}

.storm:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -150px;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0px;
  content: '';
  -webkit-animation: strome 5s ease-in infinite;
  animation: strome 5s ease-in infinite;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Now... both storm on left and right will be synchronized, which does not offer the best effect... Up to you to move foward now

Comment: Works :D Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> The `:after` and `:before` Pseudo-Elements can't be used twice for
>   same div/id/class/etc.

In your case, you can use `cloud class` for duplicating storm.

```
.cloud1:before {
     position: absolute;
     top:-150px;
     right:100px;
     bottom: 0;
     left:0px;
     content: '';
     -webkit-animation: strome 5s ease-in infinite;
             animation: strome 5s ease-in infinite;
     z-index: 9999;
}
```

see codepen: https://codepen.io/vaishalik3/pen/ERLrVe

Hope this helps :)